# Why aren't my switches changing the color of my view?

Tags: swift

This is my first post to stack overflow and hopefully not my last, considering asking questions only makes you smarter!

Basically, iv'e come to a stump. In my code, I have a UIView that I'm trying to change the color of with switches. In my viewDidLoad() method, I have it default to a black background. When I flip the switch, I want to be able to call my updateColor() method but I'm unsure how to do this. I will post my class below.

```
func updateColor() {

    var red: CGFloat = 0
    var green: CGFloat = 0
    var blue: CGFloat = 0

    if redSwitch.isOn {
        red = 1
    }
    if greenSwitch.isOn {
        green = 1
    }
    if blueSwitch.isOn {
        blue = 1
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    coilorView.backgroundColor = .black
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBOutlet weak var coilorView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var redSwitch: UISwitch!
@IBOutlet weak var greenSwitch: UISwitch!
@IBOutlet weak var blueSwitch: UISwitch!
@IBAction func switchChanged(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    if sender.isOn {

    }else{
        return coilorView.backgroundColor = .black
    }
```

---

Any help would be appreciated! Again, my end goal is for my switches to be able to change the color of my view.

-Jason
(Beginner)

Answer (score 0):

```
@IBAction func switchChanged(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    coilorView.backgroundColor = updateColor()
}


func updateColor() -> UIColor {
    return UIColor(red: redSwitch.isOn ? 1 : 0, green: greenSwitch.isOn ? 1 : 0, blue: blueSwitch.isOn ? 1 : 0, alpha: 1)
}
```

You just need to have the updateColor function create and return a color to be used in the switchChanged.

To be honest, you don't even need updateColor.  You could just also do:

```
@IBAction func switchChanged(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    coilorView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: redSwitch.isOn ? 1 : 0, green: greenSwitch.isOn ? 1 : 0, blue: blueSwitch.isOn ? 1 : 0, alpha: 1)
}
```

if you do stick with the updateColor function as I defined above, you should also use it to set the default black in viewDidLoad

Comment: Thanks man, I'm still trying to understand that return function. I think I need to recap on my functions and parameters lesson because It seems that should've been the way I wrote the code in the first place to save time and space.

Comment: @Jason The (switch.is on ? 1 : 0 ) blocks I believe are called ternary operators.  From Apple Docs: "The ternary conditional operator is a special operator with three parts, which takes the form question ? answer1 : answer2.". If this worked, don't forget to accept it as an answer.

Answer (score -2):

```
// modify the function to this , which returns the updated color after the conditions 

func updateColor() -> UIColor  {

var red: CGFloat = 0
var green: CGFloat = 0
var blue: CGFloat = 0

if redSwitch.isOn {
    red = 1
}
if greenSwitch.isOn {
    green = 1
}
if blueSwitch.isOn {
    blue = 1
}
let updatedColor = UIColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: 1.0)
return updatedColor
}

//Now you may call this function.
@IBAction func switchChanged(_ sender: UISwitch) {
   coilorView.backgroundColor = updateColor()
}
```